# Getting back to registration page with message or alert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to redirect to a registration page with a message if the details were already found in database? I am using node.js,express.js and mongodb.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply make an API call to the back-end and check in the database if the details already exist, and send a response to the front-end for redirect to the desired page

Comment: response.redirect(route) will redirect me to the registration page again but I need help in redirecting to the registration page with a message like User already registered.I tried using alert but it isn't working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used flash messages to solve the problem

```
const flash=require("express-flash");
const session=require("express-session");
app.use(session({
secret:"random text",
resave:false,
saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(flash());
```

Note that You can only use flash with sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using Native MongoDB, you can use the `db.collection.find({_id: userId})`

If you are using the mongoose framework with MongoDB, you can use the model.findById() method to check whether a user is registered in your database or not, it is something like this,

```
 app.post("/registrationpage", function(req, res){
 model.findById(userId,function(err, foundUser){
  if(foundUser){
   res.redirect("/registrationpage") 
  }else{
    Register user to database
   }
 })
})
```

Now since you are using Node.js, alert() is not a pre-defined function in it, Node.js is not intended for writing desktop applications(not directly), it is mainly for server-side javascript applications. However, you can use frameworks like AppJS, NW.js or Electron.